# Tkinter. Некорректная работа табуляции строк

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, строковый-литерал

Имеется меню

```
from tkinter import *
# del globals()['Image']
# from tkinter import ttk
# from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw, ImageTk


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title('Icon Creator')

        # self.iconphoto(True, PhotoImage(file='favicon.png'))
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        menu = Menu(self)
        self.config(menu=menu)

        # self.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('favicon.png'))

        filemenu = Menu(menu, tearoff=0)

        # filemenu.add_command(label='Открыть\t\tCtrl+O', image=self.image)

        filemenu.add_command(label='Новый\tCtrl+O')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Сохранить\tCtrl+O')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Сохранить как\tCtrl+O')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Закрыть\tCtrl+O')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Выйти\tCtrl+O')
        menu.add_cascade(label='Файл', menu=filemenu)

        
if __name__=="__main__":
    window = Window()
    window.mainloop()
```

При запуске табуляции не наблюдется.

> https://imgur.com/gallery/MKwJABn

Можно ли как-то любым другим способом добиться подобного?:

> https://imgur.com/gallery/aYZWEWO

Comment: Приведите минимально воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: А вообще вы где то в документации прочли - что именно здесь должны поддерживаться управляющие символы?

Comment: filemenu.add_command(label='Новый.................................................................Ctrl+O')?

Comment: Вместо точек пробелы поставьте.

Comment: Здесь пробелы форматируются в один.

Answer (score 2):

У метода add_command класса Menu имеется параметр accelerator, который позволяет выровнять информацию справа:

```
filemenu.add_command(label='Сохранить', accelerator='Ctrl+S')
```